# JSON is valid but not working when sent to Xero

Tags: javascript, json, xero-api

I have the below JSON which has been validated with https://jsonlint.com/.  However, when I run this through Xero API, it throws an error, shown below.

```js
{
  "Type": "ACCREC",
  "Status": "AUTHORISED",
  "DueDate": "2021-12-11T14:24:08Z",
  "InvoiceNumber": "PRO152125",
  "Contact": {
    "ContactID": "ddd-05f9-46dd-b4a6-2ccbb5deb330"
  },
  "LineItems": [
    "{\"Description\": \"test1\", \"Qty\": 0.30, \"UnitAmount\": 950.0, \"TaxType\": \"OUTPUT2\", \"AccountCode\": \"200\"},\n{\"Description\": \"test2\", \"Qty\": 0.30, \"UnitAmount\": 300.0, \"TaxType\": \"OUTPUT2\", \"AccountCode\": \"200\"}"
  ]
}
```

```js
{
  "ErrorNumber": 14,
  "Type": "PostDataInvalidException",
  "Message": "JSON for post data was invalid,Error converting value \"{\"Description\": \"test1\", \"Qty\": 0.30, \"UnitAmount\": 950.0, \"TaxType\": \"OUTPUT2\", \"AccountCode\": \"200\"},\n{\"Description\": \"test2\", \"Qty\": 0.30, \"UnitAmount\": 300.0, \"TaxType\": \"OUTPUT2\", \"AccountCode\": \"200\"}\" to type 'Xero.API.Library.DataContracts.LineItem'. Path 'LineItems[0]', line 1, position 417."
}
```

Can anyone help with why this is happening?

Comment: Is there any reason that you are using JSON as String inside LineItems ?

Comment: I think the double quotes are being added automatically by Zapier when trying to send the data.  Not sure how to stop this happening.

Comment: JSON and javascript objects are not the same thing. Right now you have a mixture of both, which isn't going to work.  Zapier is sending JSON (assuming it's what's generating the contents of `LineItems`); you'll need to `JSON.parse` that before inserting it into the rest of your object.

Comment: If you are using JS Try to use RegExp to clean LineItems, Something Like this

string.replace(/[\n"\&\r\t\b\f]/g, '\\$&');

Comment: There is no reason to resort to regex here, and you'd likely break things in the process. `JSON.parse()` was designed for this purpose.

Comment: @DanielBeck agree with you, I was thinking he is already using JSON.parse(). However sometimes JSON.parse() fail to do so based on incoming data

Comment: When I use JSON.parse() Zapier throws an internal error "Error parsing response" so the JSON doesn't even get sent to Xero.

Comment: @MMRahman "However sometimes JSON.parse() fail to do so based on incoming data" Only if the data is invalid JSON. In which case regex is going to cause even more problems.

Answer (score 0):

API are trying to deserialize your json to the class like

```
class MyClass 
{ 
    ..properties

  List<LineItem> LineItems...
}

class LineItem
{
  ... properties inside of the string
}
```

your json is valid but it is

```
class MyClass 
{ 
    ..properties

  List<string> LineItems...
}
```

Api serializer can not convert List< string > to List< LineItem >. This is what causes the error

you can fix json this way

```
  var jsonObject=GetFixedJsonObject(json);
  
  var fixedJson=jsonObject.ToString();


public JObject GetFixedJsonObject(string json)
{
    var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    
    var jsonLineItems = "[" + (string)jsonObject["LineItems"][0] + "]";
    
    jsonObject["LineItems"] = JArray.Parse(jsonLineItems);
    
    return jsonObject;
}
```

fixed json

```
{
  "Type": "ACCREC",
  "Status": "AUTHORISED",
  "DueDate": "2021-12-11T14:24:08Z",
  "InvoiceNumber": "PRO152125",
  "Contact": {
    "ContactID": "ddd-05f9-46dd-b4a6-2ccbb5deb330"
  },
  "LineItems": [
    {
      "Description": "test1",
      "Qty": 0.3,
      "UnitAmount": 950.0,
      "TaxType": "OUTPUT2",
      "AccountCode": "200"
    },
    {
      "Description": "test2",
      "Qty": 0.3,
      "UnitAmount": 300.0,
      "TaxType": "OUTPUT2",
      "AccountCode": "200"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You've got quotes around your line item, meaning it's just being seen as one big string. Try this:

```
{
    "Type": "ACCREC",
    "Status": "AUTHORISED",
    "DueDate": "2021-12-11T14:24:08Z",
    "InvoiceNumber": "PRO152125",
    "Contact": {
        "ContactID": "ddd-05f9-46dd-b4a6-2ccbb5deb330"
    },
    "LineItems": [{

        "Description": "test1",
        "Qty": 0.30,
        "UnitAmount": 950.0,
        "TaxType": "OUTPUT2",
        "AccountCode": "200"
    }, {
        "Description": "test2",
        "Qty": 0.30,
        "UnitAmount": 300.0,
        "TaxType": "OUTPUT2",
        "AccountCode": "200"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Is it a valid JSON Object?

Comment: Not anymore, it isn't.

Comment: I think the double quotes are being added automatically by Zapier when trying to send the data. Not sure how to stop this happening.

Comment: Edited for validity.